# Unable to click element via Xpath but can find it via ID

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, xpath

I am trying to delete every row in a table untill there are none left, only then do I want to continue with the rest of my test case. For this reason I'm using an if/else statement. As part of this statement I need to select the first row, click the delete button and then confirm my action by clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>. The problem is in this last action. I can find the <kbd>OK</kbd> via the `findElement by.id` but not via class and text value. Problem is that the `ID` is only reliable for deleting the first row as the application uses auto generated `ID's`. That is why I'm trying to find the <kbd>OK</kbd> via it's class and text value.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("first row of the table")) != null)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("first row of the table")).click(); //select row
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='button' and text()='Delete']")).click(); //click delete button
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ext-gen483"))); //wait untill the OK button (id=ext-gen483) in dialog box is visible to confirm delete
/** this section is built in to find out why I cant find the OK button. First I catch and print the class and text for the OK button via the id. */
            String Klasis = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen483")).getAttribute("Class");
            System.out.println("Value of Class = "+Klasis);
            String Tekstis = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen483")).getText();
            System.out.println("Value of  Text = "+Tekstis);
            String xpathOK = "//*[@class='"+Klasis+"'"+" and text()='"+Tekstis+"']";
            System.out.println(xpathOK);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOK)).click();
        }
else
```

The print actions result in:

```
Value of Class =  x-btn-text
Value of  Text = OK
//*[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='OK']
```

But the button cant be clicked: ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

However, if I use the following code to click the <kbd>OK</kbd>, it works just fine:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen483")).click();
```

This is the line of code representing the OK button:

```
<button class=" x-btn-text" id="ext-gen483" type="button">OK</button>
```

As a result of a suggestion that the extra space in the class might be getting in the way I changed the code so that it no longer uses the class but the button attribute:

```
            String Klasis = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen483")).getAttribute("Class");
            System.out.println("Value of Class = "+Klasis);
            String Tekstis = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen483")).getText();
            System.out.println("Value of  Text = "+Tekstis);
            String Typeis = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen483")).getAttribute("Type");
            System.out.println("Value of  Type = "+Typeis);
            String xpathOK = "//*[@type='"+Typeis+"'"+" and text()='"+Tekstis+"']";
            System.out.println(xpathOK);
            //driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen483")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOK)).click();
```

The print actions result in:

```
Value of Class =  x-btn-text
Value of  Text = OK
Value of  Type = button
//*[@type='button' and text()='OK']
```

But it still fails on the last line with the same message:ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

## Edit

there are 2 buttons that comply to my findelement statement. If I then choose to click the second it works!

```
List<WebElement> listOfOKbut = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Ja']")); 
System.out.println("aantal ja knoppen:"+listOfOKbut.size()); if(listOfOKbut.size() >= 2) { 
  listOfOKbut.get(1).click();
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but may it be that the space in the classname is somehow irritating the xpath?

Comment: Thanks for your input. As per your suggestion I've changed the code so it uses type instead of class. still the same result though.

Comment: How many elemtents do you get with driver.findElements(By.id("ext-gen483")).size() ?

Comment: This is indeed the problem, there are 2 buttons that comply to my findelement statement. If I then choose to click the second it works!           List<WebElement> listOfOKbut = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Ja']"));
          System.out.println("aantal ja knoppen:"+listOfOKbut.size());
          if(listOfOKbut.size() >= 2) {
           listOfOKbut.get(1).click();

Comment: haha, didn't we try this yesterday and it didn't work?

Comment: different problem but looks like the same solution. The problem from yesterday is also solved now, allhough how I have no idea. Posted the answer in the original post...

Answer (score 0):

try using contains instead of "=" for the @class part:

```
String xpathOK = "//*[contains(@class,'x-btn-text') and text()='OK']";
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this too, still fails with same message.

Comment: @Hugo, let's see if you can use xpath with the id -> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='ext-gen483']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

To find an element more accurately use the following methods

1. `String xpath = "//button[contains(@class,'x-btn-text') and text()='OK']"`
2. Find the parent element of button whose `class or id` is constant.
     `xpath = "//parent//button[contains(@class,'x-btn-text') and text()='OK']"`